# Unable to print array in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, express

Here is my code in routes

```
router.get('/chkjson', function(req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        var ItemArray = [];
        var myset = [];

        var query = connection.query('SELECT `db_name` FROM `database`',function(err,rows)
        {
            ItemArray.push({
                allDb : []
            });
            var k=0;
            for (var i in rows) {
                    retset = JSON.stringify(rows[i]);
                    var jsonset =  JSON.parse(retset);
                    console.log(ItemArray);
                    console.log("========");
                    myset.push(ItemArray);
                    ItemArray[0].allDb.push(jsonset.db_name);
            }
        });
        console.log(myset);   //blank array
        console.log("-----");
        console.log(ItemArray);   //blank array
        console.log("-----");
            res.render( 'new/post-select-table', 
                { 
                    title: 'Select Database',
                    session_store:req.session,
                });
        });
});
```

I'm getting blank array when I'm trying to print array outside for loop. Can anyone help me where im going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`connection.query()` is asynchronous, and in your code you're logging `ItemArray` outside of the callback of your query. The array will be empty since it isn't set to anything yet (i.e. your callback wouldn't have fired yet with the results). The following moves your `console.log`s and render function outside of the for loop, but inside of the callback, so it should print your final results for ItemArray as expected:

```
router.get('/chkjson', function(req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        var ItemArray = [];
        var myset = [];

        var query = connection.query('SELECT `db_name` FROM `database`',function(err,rows)
        {
            ItemArray.push({
                allDb : []
            });
            var k=0;
            for (var i in rows) {
                    retset = JSON.stringify(rows[i]);
                    var jsonset =  JSON.parse(retset);
                    console.log(ItemArray);
                    console.log("========");
                    myset.push(ItemArray);
                    ItemArray[0].allDb.push(jsonset.db_name);
            }

            console.log(myset);   //blank array
            console.log("-----");
            console.log(ItemArray);   //blank array
            console.log("-----");
                res.render( 'new/post-select-table',
                    {
                        title: 'Select Database',
                        session_store:req.session,
                    });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function in the query is called asynchronously, your prints are executed before the data is populated in the arrays.

You have to call `res.render` asynchronously from the callback. I dont understand all the operations in your code but here is an example of chaining a query and the response:

```
router.get('/chkjson', function(req, res, next) {
  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    connection.query('SELECT `db_name` FROM `database`',function(err,rows) {
      var myset = [], row;
      for (row in rows) {
        myset.push(row);
      }
      res.render( 'new/post-select-table', { 
        title: 'Select Database',
        session_store:req.session,
        set: myset
      }); 
    });
  });
});
```

If you need to chain requests, you can use [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) to handle synchronisation easily, or modularise your code to avoid callback hell.

Example:

```
var connection, row1, row2
router.get('/chkjson', handleRequest);
function handleRequest (req, res, next) {
  req.getConnection(onGotConnection);
}
function onGotConnection(err,conn) {
  connection = conn;
  connection.query(query1, onGotEntity1);
}
function onGotEntity1(err,rows) {
  rows1 = rows

  connection.query(query2, onGotEntity2);
}
function onGotEntity2(err,rows) {
   row2 = rows

   // render view
   res.render( 'new/post-select-table', { 
      k1: rows1,
      k2: rows2 
   }); 
}
```

But I recommend using promises that are a lot easier to read (and managing errors):

```
mysql.createConnection(opts).then(function(conn){
    connection = conn;
    return connection.query(query1);
}).then(function(rows){ 
    return connection.query(query2);
}).then(function(rows){
    // render view
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yoann. But what if I have to make multiple connection.query() statements. Then how I can pass multiple results from multiple queries?

Comment: I have updated my answer in that way. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just return the array and push it to global variables?

```
var query = connection.query("soandso", function(err, result) {
    var allDb = [];

    return allDb;
}

ItemArray.push(query);
```